# fscanf reading into a double array strange values

Tags: c, arrays, double, scanf

The following code has the intent of reading doubles from a file and putting them into an array. Quite simple.

```
double arr[100];
int i = 0; 

while(fscanf(fin, "%lf", &arr[i]) != EOF) 
    i++;
```

However when I print the array I get weird values. If I substitute the array variable with a regular double variable and inside the previously mentioned while loop print the value of this variable it gets printed correctly. What is wrong with the mentioned code? I tried initializing all values in the array beforehand, but, of course, that was no help either.

Comment: First of all you have to add a condition so `i` doesn't get to high and overwrites memory outside of the array. Second, did you print `i` and `arr[i]` inside the loop as well?

Comment: What you posted should work. I think you're not showing us the real code, but a "simplified" version.

Comment: What he posted should not work; if there are non-double values in file, it would be an infinite loop

Comment: @user411313 The man page for `fscanf()` says: "... EOF  is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or *a matching failure occurs*.  EOF is also returned if a read error occurs..."

Comment: Can you post the file and the results you get?

Comment: Yeah, should work, works here. Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to parenthesis around the array.  For example, in the code, you have "&arr[i]".  This is the same as (&arr)[i] which means get the address of the array pointer (a pointer to a pointer) with an offset of i.  This could offset the writings by a few bits, which makes the output seem funky.

Add parenthesis to make it like this:  "&(arr[i])"

```
double arr[100];
int i = 0; 

while(fscanf(fin, "%lf", &(arr[i])) != EOF) 
    i++;
```

Comment: This is not correct, array subscripting has higher precedence than address-of.